# select only text between quotes in VB

Tags: vb.net

Is it some function which can return me text between qoutes.? Text before and between quotes is variable length. I find a function mid but in specify is length. I would like to get from this string text between both quots(APP_STATUS_RUNNING) and (PRIMARY):

string: `Error gim_icon_cfg_1 Application with DBID 736 has status "APP_STATUS_RUNNING", runmode "PRIMARY"`

Thank you

EDIT: I try to get output to the label but show me error:BC30452: Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and '1-dimensional array of String'.

```
Dim output As String = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() 
Dim StandardError As String = myProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd() 

Dim Splitted() As String 
Splitted = Split(output, """") 
Label1.text="Ahoj " & Splitted & "Error " & StandardError
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split your string by quotes beeing the delimiter `Split(InputString, """")` the odd numbers of the output array then are the strings between quotes, the even numbers are the rest.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Dim InputString As String
    InputString = "Error gim_icon_cfg_1 Application with DBID 736 has status ""APP_STATUS_RUNNING"", runmode ""PRIMARY"""
    
    Dim Splitted() As String
    Splitted = Split(InputString, """")
    
    ' between quotes (all odd numbers)
    Debug.Print Splitted(1)   ' APP_STATUS_RUNNING
    Debug.Print Splitted(3)   ' PRIMARY

    ' rest (all even numbers)
    Debug.Print Splitted(0)   ' Error gim_icon_cfg_1 Application with DBID 736 has status 
    Debug.Print Splitted(2)   ' , runmode 
End Sub
```

Comment: I try to get output to the label but show me error:BC30452: Operator '&' is not defined for types 'String' and '1-dimensional array of String'.                                                               
    Dim output As String = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
   Dim StandardError As String = myProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd()

 Dim Splitted() As String
    Splitted = Split(output, """")
   
  Label1.text="Ahoj " & Splitted & "Error " & StandardError

Comment: @FiínekCahů is that a question? I don't get what you want to achieve with your comment. Please not that code in comments gets unreadable if you want to add something to your question please edit your original question and add it there.

Comment: `Splitted` is an array you need to use `Splitted(1)` to get the text between the first pair of quotes and `Splitted(3)` to get the text between the second pair of quotes.

Comment: but how? :( I dont know

Comment: Exactly like I said `"Ahoj " & Splitted(1) & "Error " & StandardError`

Comment: I tried it but with error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Then that means your string `output` had no quotes.

Comment: Contain quotes: Error gim_icon_cfg_1 Application with DBID 736 has status "APP_STATUS_RUNNING", runmode "PRIMARY"

Comment: Well it might conaint something that looks like quotes but they are not the same quotes that you have in VB. There exist different quotes (like smart quotes). Can you check the output of `Debug.Print Asc(Mid(output, InStr(output, "APP_STATUS_RUNNING") - 1, 1)), Asc(Mid(output, InStr(output, "APP_STATUS_RUNNING") + 18, 1))` please?

Comment: I edited input string and output was changed.

Comment: @FiínekCahů Please not that you cannot change the intire question to a new one. Please keep the original quesiton and if you want to ask something new then start a new question. We can only handle one question per post. • I reverted your question to the old one. Please mark this question as solved. Then open up a new question.

Comment: Sorry, but I cant post next question.

Answer (score 2):

Or:
The follow code gives you what you are trying to have.
In practice you can search patterns that  are between quotes then get from each element the first element sliced by quote (which means quote = 0 element = 1 other quote = 2)

```
Dim s As String = "Error gim_icon_cfg_1 Application With DBID 736 has status ""APP_STATUS_RUNNING"", runmode ""PRIMARY"""
Dim parts() As String = s.Split(" "c).Where(Function(el) el Like "*""*""*").Select(Function(el) el.Split(""""c)(1)).ToArray
```